# Splitting an entity into 2 tables with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have 2 tables in my database (Oracle) which I would like to merge into one entity.
I'm using Entity Framework 4.1 code first approach (with existing database) so everything works fine.

The tables structure:

Table Document_Metadata:

```
Item       NUMBER(2)   PK
Version    NUMBER(2)   PK 
DocDate    DATE        PK
RepType    NUMBER(2)   PK
ValueType  NUMBER(2)   PK
DocId      NUMBER(5)   NOT NULL FK -> Document table
User       VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL
RowVersion DATE        NOT NULL
```

Table Document:

```
ID         NUMBER(5)   PK
Doc        LONGRAW     
User       VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL
RowVersion DATE        NOT NULL
```

Is there a way to accomplish that, and if so how would I do that?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I'm no expert but I read about Entity Splitting feature that is provided by Entity Framework. I'm pretty sure you can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. If this is "one to one" relation, maybe you could go with table per type inheritance, and inherit Document_Metadata class from Document class. So you would have one entity object for both tables. But for that to work DocID would have to be PK in Document_Metadata and I think that primary key column names for both tables would have to be same (rename ID to DocID in Document table). But that requires changes in your database model.

Comment: I tried various ways to accomplish entity splitting with these 2 tables with no luck. I guess you are right, I can't do that. Well, I have to build these tables into 2 separate classes with navigation properties. Thanks for your time and effort.